# How does facebook knows when you stopped in an article/picture

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, I don't know if this is the right place to post this question. If it is, I'm sorry.

Everytime you go through `facebook newsfeed` you stop at some image to look at it or an article that you found interesting but **didn't click on it**. If you go to some page and come back to the `newsfeed`you will likely see the same image on the top of your `newsfeed`.

I tried to look for some function/algorithm but didn't find any.

Others website doesn't have such feature e.g. `Quora` and `mySpace`.

My question here is: **How does Facebook knows that you stopped to look at that picture/article?** if such function exists or it's only my stupid mind playing tricks on me.

Comment: I haven't noticed that behaviour in Facebook.

Comment: @nnnnnn Since I start using `facebook` I got to see a lot of pictures that I stop to look at but didn't click on it. They have nothing to do with me (not a friend that I go to his profile or anything alike).

Comment: @nnnnnn this kind of thing does happen on Twitter, so some videos all you need to do is scroll to them and they start playing.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: @DannyGoodall - Sure, I've seen videos start to play as they scroll into view. But I haven't noticed them later appearing at the top of the news feed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess facebook detect your scroll position.

Every website can run a script that detect your scroll position every second, and then know if you're stopped (stay on the same position or same range of pixels for a while) in a post, picture or a video. Then you can decide if the user find the content interesting or not.

It's simple with jQuery:

```
var s = $('body').scrollTop();
```